# Combine two Convert Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression

**Scenario**:

Some entity classes:

```
public class BookEntity
{
    public int IdBook { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class StudentEntity
{
    public int IdStudent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LoanEntity
{
    public int IdLoan { get; set; }
    public StudentEntity Student { get; set; }
    public BookEntity Book { get; set; }
}
```

And some data transfer object classes:

```
public class BookDTO
{
    public int IdBook { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDTO
{
    public int IdStudent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LoanDTO
{
    public int IdLoan { get; set; }
    public StudentDTO Student { get; set; }
    public BookDTO Book { get; set; }
}
```

And I already have this expressions (that convert entity in dto):

```
Expression<Func<BookEntity, BookDTO>> pred1 = e => new BookDTO
{
    IdBook = e.IdBook,
    Title = e.Title
};

Expression<Func<StudentEntity, StudentDTO>> pred2 = e => new StudentDTO
{
    IdStudent = e.IdStudent,
    Name = e.Name
};
```

**Goal:**
Now I want to create an expression that convert `LoanEntity` in `LoanDTO`. Something like:

```
Expression<Func<LoanEntity, LoanDTO>> pred3 = e => new LoanDTO
{
    IdLoan = e.IdLoan,
    Book = new BookDTO
    {
        IdBook = e.Book.IdBook,
        Title = e.Book.Title
    },
    Student = new StudentDTO
    {
        IdStudent = e.Student.IdStudent,
        Name = e.Student.Name
    }
};
```

**The Problem:**

If you notice the `pred3` expression is formed by the same code of `pred1` and `pred2` expression.

So is it possible to create `pred3` by using `pred1` and `pred2` to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `Install-Package AutoMapper`? Its a library that solves your problem completely.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
  cfg.CreateMap<LoanEntity, LoanDTO>();
  cfg.CreateMap<BookEntity, BookDTO>();
  cfg.CreateMap<StudentEntity, StudentDTO>();
});
var mapper = new ExpressionBuilder(config);

Expression<Func<LoanEntity, LoanDTO>> mappingExpression = mapper.CreateMapExpression<LoanEntity, LoanDTO>();
```

Comment: Solves the root problem, and considering that EF doesn't support `Expression.Invoke()` according to @IvanStoev, would be the approach to go for.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible but you will have to call `Compile()` method in expressions `pred1` and `pred2` to invoke it:

```
Expression<Func<LoanEntity, LoanDTO>> pred3 = e => new LoanDTO
{
    IdLoan = e.IdLoan,
    Book = pred1.Compile()(e.Book),
    Student = pred2.Compile()(e.Student)
};
```

But you can only works with `Func<,>`:

```
Func<BookEntity, BookDTO> pred1 = e => new BookDTO
{
    IdBook = e.IdBook,
    Title = e.Title
};

Func<StudentEntity, StudentDTO> pred2 = e => new StudentDTO
{
    IdStudent = e.IdStudent,
    Name = e.Name
};
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
Func<LoanEntity, LoanDTO> pred3 = e => new LoanDTO
{
    IdLoan = e.IdLoan,
    Book = pred1(e.Book),
    Student = pred2(e.Student)
};
```